# How to add CI error bars and edit an interception plot in plot_model for a glmer?

Tags: r, plot, mixed-models

I am studying how long it takes for individuals diagnosed with a psychiatric condition, compared to healthy individuals, to detect fearful, happy and neutral emotional faces.

I am performining analysis with Generalized Linear Mixed Model, and the best-fitting model was the following:

```
gmod3.5 <- glmer(rt ~ Group * Emotion + trialnum2 +(1+Emotion|ID)+(1|Actor), data=CFS_21, family=Gamma(link="identity"))
```

The factor group has two levels (SZ, CG), the factor emotion has tree leves (F, H, N) and age is centered.

For the plot, I wrote the following code:

```
set_theme(base = theme_classic(), #To remove the background color and the grids
          axis.title.size = 1.0,  #To change axis title size
          axis.textsize.x = 1.0,  #To change x axis text size
          axis.textsize.y = 1.0,
          legend.item.backcol = "white",
          legend.item.bordercol = "white",
          legend.backgroundcol = "white",
          legend.inside = TRUE)

p<-plot_model(gmod3.5, type = "int", vars = c("Emotion", "Group", "trialnum2"),
           title="Response time per group considering the emotion",
           colors = "Set2",
           show.values = TRUE,
           value.offset = .2,
           value.size = 2,
           dot.size = 2,
           line.size = 1,
           width = 1)

p + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 4), breaks = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4))
```

[image: Click here to see the GLMM plot]

However, I need to use CI for the error bars and to make the groups (CG and SZ) closer to each other

Does anyone known how to do this using the plot_model function?

Comment: Please add the libraries you're using to your example.

Comment: Some reproducible data would be good too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example